# Error at 15:9 'if' cannot be used as a variable or function name

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am making a script, which is close to done, so I’m trying to get it plotted on the chart using pine editor, but I keep getting this error: Error at 15:9 'if' cannot be used as a variable or function name.

I have made a small snippet from the script to see if the error is where the error shows or maybe I could have been somewhere else in the script.
But since I still get the same error I assume the error is somewhere in the code.

The error is always marked under the 2nd last (end) if.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Test Script", overlay=true)

var float[] msb_signals_rsi = array.new_float(0)
var float last_msb_rsi = na

// Update last 5 bars for MSB signals
if (na(last_msb_rsi) == false)
    array.push(msb_signals_rsi, last_msb_rsi)
    if (array.size(msb_signals_rsi) > 5)
        array.shift(msb_signals_rsi)
    end if
end if
```

I feel I have tried to use the 4 spaces rule in different ways aka placing the last end if at 0 and 4 hence moving the 2nd last end if to 4 and 8. Anyways I’m stock and I hope someone can help me out :)`your text`

Comment: Looking at https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Conditional_structures.html#if-structure, it doesn't look like you need `end if`